# Windows 10 Touch Screen Compatiable Comic Reader

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchscreen, reader

I've recently purchased a Lenovo Yoga Book which I am intending to use mostly as a tablet. I want to read my comic collection (mostly CBZ and CBR files) on here but have had a hard time finding a Windows App that has touchscreen support.

I originally tried to use ComicRack as I have used this in the past but I have found that I can not get the touchscreen functionality it is suppose to have working and can not find any useful documentation or community to ask for help (In a reddit thread I found everyone stated that they never got it working).

The next most popular I've seen is YacReader but it also does not appear to be touchscreen friendly. After looking around I have not been able to find any programs that mention they are touch screen friendly for Windows.

Does anyone have any suggestions for Windows Applications that are touch screen friendly for reading comics? Its getting to the point I'm debating running BlueStacks so I can emulate PerfectViewer or the Android version of ComicRack.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ComicRack. It frustrated me to hell that I couldn't get the touchscreen functionality to work, but then I reviewed the ComicRack manual and learned what the "gestures" are. See attached image. "Gesture 3," which is set for "next page" is a small square area in the top right corner of the screen just under the toolbar. When I say small I mean I can cover the entire square with my finger, but it was there, and "gesture 1" for "previous page" is in the opposite corner on the left. I can now finally use ComicRack as my default comic book reader. Hope this answer helps anyone else that was looking for help. [image: Page 67 from ComicRack Manual 5th edition]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Comic Collection Browser (download from [www.viamaev.nl](http://www.viamaev.nl)).
It was originally created for viewing comics on the awesome Hi13 Windows tablet, so it has a great touch interface.

(disclosure: I am the creator of the app :) )

Kind regards  Wim